# How to assign a numbering scheme to TreeNodes based on it's position

Tags: c#, treeview

I have a TreeView control in a Windows Forms application that is displaying my own subclass of TreeNode. I need to display a number along with each nodes' text indicating its position in the tree, like 1 for the root, 1.1 for its first child, 1.2 for its second child, etc. I'm using C#

Answer (score 1):

When populating the tree nodes, I'm assuming you're using a recursive method.  Make one of the parameters the parent node tag, such as the first child of the root node one be "1", it's simblings "2", "3", etc.

```
private void AddNode(
    List<Data> data, string parentKey, Node parent)
{
    var parentLevel = parent.Tag;
    var counter = 1;
    foreach(var item in 
        data.Where(x => x.ParentKey == parentKey))
    {
        var node = new TreeNode() 
            { Tag = $"{parentLevel}.{counter++}" };

        node.Text = $"{node.Tag} {item.Text}";

        parentNode.Nodes.Add(node);

        AddNode(data, item.Key, node);
    }
}
```